# Ant design table rowSelection uncompatible with expandedRowRender

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant design, when I use both rowSelection and expandedRowRender for a table, the rowSelection doesn't work correctly, it will always choose the first row whenever I choose any row. When I comment out the expandedRowRender, rowSelection works again.

```
<Table
                    pagination={{
                        hideOnSinglePage: true,
                    }}
                    expandedRowRender={record => {
                        const changeOrder = newOrderValue => {
                            record = newOrderValue;
                        };
                        return (
                            <div className='order-management__table__expandable'>
                                <TableOrderDetail orders={[record]} changeOrder={changeOrder} />
                            </div>
                        );
                    }}
                    rowSelection={{ rowSelection }}
                    columns={columns}
                    dataSource={orders}
                ></Table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, always selected first line. I identified that I was returning the index of the row in the property of the table:

`rowKey={(record, index) => index}`

Changing it to:

`rowKey={(record, index) => record.id}`

Solved for me.